# How to search content in getstream

Tags: getstream-io

How to filter activities in e.g. If I want to filter activity based on some content, it should list all the activities which had that content. Is there any such functionality provided by getstream?

Could you please suggest ?

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing. If we assume GetStream is like Facebook, Facebook doesn't really let you search their feed, and in general I think it's a tricky thing to do. What Facebook DOES do is have that SLOW search up at the top (you can tell it takes a long time and half the time doesn't even really have good results). If we accepted that our search would be slow we can paginate through a list of all the objects in our feed from GetStream then search through them on our site. Not a good solution but haven't really seen any other ones.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for the same thing. If we assume GetStream is like Facebook, Facebook doesn't really let you search their feed, and in general I think it's a tricky thing to do. What Facebook DOES do is have that SLOW search up at the top (you can tell it takes a long time and half the time doesn't even really have good results). If we accepted that our search would be slow we can paginate through a list of all the objects in our feed from GetStream then search through them on our site. Not a good solution but haven't really seen any other ones.